# Alternative syntax for C++, a la Genie for Vala?

Tags: c++, programming-languages, vala, genie

The Vala language compiler can handle a very different looking syntax, Genie, which arguably could be considered a different language or an alternative syntax for one language.   AFIK, anything you can do in Vala, you can write in Genie (ignoring work-in-progress details, bugs) to the delight of anyone who doesn't like curly brackets.

Is there some language or alternative syntax bearing the same relation to standard C++ that Genie has with Vala?  It should allow doing anything that one might do in C++.  (It need not be readable by the normal C++ compilers, however - I don't expect that at this point in time.)

(Side issue: Genie/Vala is the only example I can think of now. Are there other examples?)

Comment: "It should allow doing anything that one might do in C++." You'll need to be more specific than that. Any Turing-complete language can do anything that one might do in C++.

Comment: C++ is a hard enough language to write a compiler for.  Can't imagine anyone writing a compiler that can do all of C++ in addition to another language.

Comment: For Scheme, [SRFI 49](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-49/srfi-49.html) documents an indentation-based syntax, termed *I-expressions*, that avoids parentheses.

Comment: I'm hoping for some alternative syntax with an explicit "function" keyword, or something, to allow grepping for all methods declarations in a source file. Perhaps more readable type declarations. Perhaps alternatives to curly brackets (thought they're fine by me) or overall easier to parse?

Comment: @Marcelo: yes, that is the idea.  Now where is something that for C++?

Comment: @user470379: the phrase "semantically isomorphic" from the SPECS paper seems to capture what I mean

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[SPECS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significantly_Prettier_and_Easier_C%2B%2B_Syntax)

Comment: direct link: http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~damian/papers/HTML/ModestProposal.html

Comment: Exactly the sort of thing I was looking for!

Comment: The article has been deleted. Are there any other relevant resources? And if so, can you summarize rather than just leaving a bare link that's susceptible to linkrot again?